# Notification - Track impressions

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a system which sends notifications to iOS apps. Now, I want to track impressions. i.e how many people have received the notification via my system. Is there a way to do this. "This is possible in Android".

Background modes/Silent-Push is not the solution as it does not work when the app is killed. One way I was able to figure out was that I would just update the badge no. and check the badge no. when the user opens the app. Not the most time efficient way, but works with a caveat, which is that it still wouldn't assure me that the source of the notification was my system.

As per my understanding, Apple docs, various articles I've read and stack overflow, there is no way to know if the user has received the notification, unless he clicks on it, which beats the idea of impressions for me. Does someone know a way/hack around this??

Comment: Surely an impression is a notification seen, not just received?

Comment: Seen and received are very ambiguous in the iOS system. A user might see the notification, but might not click on it or might have received but has not seen it. So for me, the differentiation is a). notification delivered(impression),seen or not. b). notification tapped (conversion - again depends upon context)